# How can I start a Node.js app with forever on a port that I set on the command-line?

Tags: node.js, forever

I am trying to use this command which should work. It does not seem to pass along the environment variable when starts the server which uses Express.js. This is for this Open Source project, [Bus Ticker](https://github.com/BusTicker/BusTicker-NodeServer).

`PORT=8081; forever start ./website/app.js`

In `app.js` is has this line so I am expect that I can set the environment variable on that command-line as shown above.

`app.set('port', process.env.PORT || process.env.npm_package_config_port || 3000);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting a shell variable, not an environment variable. Yes, the distinction is confusing.

Try putting `export` at the beginning of that line.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

https://github.com/BusTicker/BusTicker-NodeServer/commit/c7084587b68075a794ec51c6e0941a295bc9e14e

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! It solved my issue. I could not run `forever` service, because one of the ports was already taken.